# How can I hide the heading and options bar in google drive

Tags: android, cordova, google-docs, inappbrowser

I want to hide the top options bar in google drive. How can I achieve that? I am using cordova inAppBrowser to open this link.

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nipvep1WpPd2JXeDdJcUlNYXM/view

I want to use `embedded=true` but I don't know how it would work. Please see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*May be this will help you*

You have to wait until your inAppBrowser page loading finishes.

```
//Set css in your inAppstyle.css
.drive-viewer-toolstrip{
    display: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

You must add an event listener:

```
var inApp = window.open('https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nipvep1WpPd2JXeDdJcUlNYXM/view', '_blank', 'location=no');
inApp.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
    inApp.insertCSS({
        file: 'inAppStyle.css'
    },onSuccess);
});
```

Use this path for your android projects file:///android_asset/{your folder}

INFO: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#android-file-system-layout

**Your JS**

```
text += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="embedURL" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open(\'drive.google.com/file/d‌​/0B_nipvep1WpPd2JXeD‌​dJcUlNYXM/view\', \'_blank\', \'location=no\')">' + data.docs[i].doc_title + '</a>';
```

**Updated JS**

```
text += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="embedURL" onClick="openthislink(\'drive.google.com/file/d‌​/0B_nipvep1WpPd2JXeD‌​dJcUlNYXM/view\')">' + data.docs[i].doc_title + '</a>';

//Create new function
function openthislink(ln)
{
    var inApp = window.open(ln, '_blank', 'location=no');
    inApp.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
        inApp.insertCSS({
            file: 'inAppStyle.css'
        },onSuccess);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using a link. How can I convert it to the thing you just told me? Here is my code. text += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="embedURL" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open(\'https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nipvep1WpPd2JXeDdJcUlNYXM/view\', \'_blank\', \'location=no\')">' + data.docs[i].doc_title + '</a>';

Comment: The code is working but sign in button is still there :(

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: onSuccess is not defined

Comment: just create new function `function onSuccess(){}` and problem will solved