# Cordova inAppBrowser InsertCSS doesn't works

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I want to open page in Cordova WebView and add some styles. I have

```
function setSize() {
            alert('Trying to load styles'); //works
           app.insertCSS({code: 'body{width: 100% !important;height: 100% !important;background-color: red !important;}'}, function(){
            alert('Styles are loaded!');
           });
         }

        function onDeviceReady() {
          var app= window.open('http://example.com','_self','location=no'); 
         app.addEventListener('loadstart', setSize());
            }
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any mistake ?

Comment: code should be like `app.addEventListener('loadstart', setSize);` . Plus do the things on `loadstop` event

Comment: it doesn't works too

Comment: Refer this doc https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/. Use the API as documented

Comment: The iframe and body should probably be full downloaded then CSS inserted, wait for it ,using a timeout then run your insertCSS.

Answer (score 0):

`inAppBrowser` is not a page from your application its a web page displays within browser of your app so to apply css into your browser elements you have to load CSS file into page of browser,

So here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892657/3840093) I have given in stack overflow before, which is working fine for that OP so try it, may be you will get success in what you wants to do.